# Simply normal sequence of $-1$'s and $1$'s as coefficients of harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Suppose $s_{n}$ is either $1$ or $-1$ for $n=1,2, 3,\ldots$ and that half the $s_{n}$'s are 1; i.e. 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\#\{i\leq n: s_{i}=1\}}{n}=\frac{1}{2}.
$$
Does then the series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{s_{n}}{n}$ converge?

The point here is that the alternating harmonic series converges, and if the $s_n$'s are the result of a fair coin flip ($-1$ for heads and $1$ for tails), then the series converges almost surely. So I'm asking about convergence for a simply normal sequence of $1$'s and $-1$'s. The sequence $1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$ is simply normal, as is the result of the coin flip (almost surely).

Comment: Is there a difference between an arbitrary simply normal sequence and one determined by fair coin flips? I don't think that there is, which would mean that the series almost surely converges.

Comment: @KSmarts Yes, there is. Simply normal, which means that half the $s_n$'s are $1$'s, is a much weaker property. For example the sequence $1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$ is simply normal but not the result of coin flips.

Comment: But isn't any simply normal sequence *potentially* the result of a series of fair coin flips? I would think that if anything, simply normal would be the stricter condition, since it gives half of the $s_n$'s are $1$'s, whereas the coin flips gives that almost surely, half of the $s_n$'s are $1$'s.

Comment: @KSmarts No, the result of a coin flip would almost surely be absolutely normal.

Comment: You say *in your question* that a sequence of fair coin flips is almost surely simply normal (though it is also almost surely absolutely normal). In any case, I don't see how you can say that any simply normal sequence is *not* the result of fair coin tosses (or die rolls, or whatever).

Comment: @KSmarts The point is that both of the facts 1) the alternating harmonic series converges and 2) the "random coefficient" series converges almost surely would be implied by the fact that "simply normal coefficient" series converges. But neither of facts 1) nor 2) implies that a "simply normal coefficient" series converges.

Comment: @KSmarts You're right that it's not technically correct to say that any particular sequence isn't the result of coin flips, but probabilists do it anyway. They would say that $1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$ isn't random (i.e. not the result of coin flips) because it's not absolutely normal. [Algorithmic randomness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmically_random_sequence) makes this precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the paper you found indicates, not every simply normal sequence of $-1$'s and $1$'s makes the series converge. For example, define the following sequence:
$$
s_n=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & : n \textrm{ is prime} \\
(-1)^n & : \textrm{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
$$
That is, we alternate between $-1$ and $1$, except for the prime terms, which are always $1$. Then, for simple normality, we have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{N_s(1,n)}{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{n}{2}+\pi(n)}{n}=\frac{1}{2}$, where $\pi$ is the prime counting function. Since $\displaystyle\sum_{p\textrm{ is prime}}\frac{1}{p}$ diverges, we know that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{s_n}{n}$ diverges as well.

So we can't say with *certainty* that the series converges.

However, since almost all real numbers are (absolutely) normal, it follows that almost all simply normal numbers are absolutely normal. Since it is easy to construct a bijection between $[0,1]$ and all seqences of $-1$'s and $1$'s (take the binary decimal, each digit is $0$ or $1$, corresponding to $-1$ and $1$ in the series, respectively), almost all of your sequences $\{s_n\}$ are absolutely normal. As the alternating sequence shows, a simply normal sequence that is not absolutely normal can still lead to a converging series. (I would guess that almost all of them do, but I'm not sure). Since an absolutely normal sequence corresponds to a random harmonic series, the series converges almost surely.

Comment: Why does the divergence of $\sum 1/p$ imply the divergence of $\sum s_{n}/n$? (You have a typo in your answer: $\sum s_{n}$ should be $\sum s_{n}/n$.)

Comment: Because for the chosen definition, $s_n$=1 for any prime $n$, and the rest of the sequence alternates. Since all of the primes except $2$ are odd, $\sum s_n/n=\sum (-1)^n/n + 2\sum (1/p) - 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I just found [this paper](http://www.stat.ualberta.ca/people/schmu/preprints/rhs.pdf) in which there's an exercise at the end claiming that "Balancing the plus and
minus signs does not guarantee convergence."

Answer (score -1):

Well I pretty sure that your series converges :)

So... as far as i understand, $s_n$ is the sequence which for each $n$ gives you either $1$ or $-1$, but not neccesarily in the order $1,-1,1,-1,1...$ Is that right?

If the sequence is $s_n=(-1)^n$ then of course the series $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{s_n}{n}$ converges. Here is a link to the alterating series test: http://www.math.com/tables/expansion/tests.htm
whether it converges to $\frac{1}{2}$ i can't say for sure but you could try to make the deference between $\frac{1}{2}$ and your series up til $n$ less then an arbitrary number, $\epsilon$. In that way you would have proved that the series equals $\frac{1}{2}$

But I'm not completely sure if we're just looking at random series with mixed up $1$ and $-1$...

Comment: I downvoted because this answer is not helpful. In particular, the alternating series test is irrelevant (as far as I can tell).